# Typescript: autocompletion isn't working, composition with reduce & optional promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, functional-programming, autocomplete

I'm trying to apply composition with typescript for the first time, I looked up for solutions I couldn't find something that fits my problem.

Generally speaking in TypeScript if we have something like this:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const open = (path: string, flags: T_FS_TYPES = "r") => fs.promises.open(path, flags);

const isExist = (path: string) => fs.existsSync(path);

const resolvePath = (path: string) =>
  path.startsWith("/") ? path : resolve(path);

open(isExistHandled(resolvePath("data")))
  .then((data) => {
    data // data will autocomplete just fine
  });
```

I tried to build a composer with reduce, but it didn't autocomplete, and until I didn't know what am I doing anymore:

```
const compose:
<T extends any | Promise<any>>(...funcs: Function[]) => (value: T) => any | Promise<any>
=
<T extends any | Promise<any>>(...funcs: Function[]) => (value) =>
  funcs.reduce<T>((v, f) => f(v), <T>value);

compose(
  resolvePath,
  isExistHandled,
  open
)("data")
  .then((data) => {
    data // I got to the point where everything is fine but it's not autocompleting here.
  });
```

So in short, I'm expecting a function to be called and take the last result of its previous and return it to the next on the chain, with autocompletion working like the first code snippet.

Comment: Given that only your outermost function call is returning a promise, your `compose` function doesn't need to handle promises at all. The actual problem with your autocomplete is that `compose` treats all those functions as `any`-returning, the `T` generic of the initial value doesn't help at all with that. Instead, try overloading (up to a certain tuple size) and exact types for each function.

Comment: You're right, but naturally it should be able to, right? Do you think it can be solved in typescript, or it's a bug in the library?

Comment: I mean when passing from one function to the next I should be able to handle all kind of returns, if now I stopped with a promise I might stop with a different thing later on.

Comment: If one function returns a promise, the next function needs to accept a promise. Otherwise it's not function composition. (There is a variant, often called `composeP`, for composition of the kleisli arrows for promises, but really it does something different.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had made a bit of research on my free time to solve the problem, I eventually found this article in which I can select the last element in an array, so I thought about providing the `...funcs` as a tuple instead.

```js
type LengthOfTuple<T extends any[]> = T extends { length: infer L } ? L : never;

type DropFirstInTuple<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => any) extends (arg: any, ...rest: infer U) => any ? U : T;

type LastInTuple<T extends any[]> = T[LengthOfTuple<DropFirstInTuple<T>>];

type Composer =
  <T extends any[]>(...funcs: T) => 
  (value: any) => ReturnType<LastInTuple<T>>;

const composer: Composer = (...funcs) => {
  return (value) => funcs.reduce((v, f) => f(v), value)
}
```

This is still too long, I hope someone will read this someday and can provide a better answer, any update for the answer is welcome...

Side note: this is only a side project, but still I'm interested to learn more, and keep this as a reference.

Article reference: https://dev.to/miracleblue/how-2-typescript-get-the-last-item-type-from-a-tuple-of-types-3fh3